# Unable to configure Firebase cloud messaging in angularjs App.

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have configured firebase cloud messaging api with my angularjs app.But as shown in [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).For Receiving message **firebase-messaging-sw.js** needs to be created and scripts to be imported.
But on importing scripts in firebase-messaging-sw.js,

> importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
>   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

how to import these scripts into **firebase-messaging-sw.js** because these are imported in **index.html** file.

> Error: importScripts is not defined.
>   Please tell how to import such file and this solution works only for chrome or for all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out..
As only these two scripts can be imported because only these two are defined in service-worker file.
Try to use service-worker,if default code doesn't workout like this:

```js
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
            .then(function (registration)
               {
                var serviceWorker;
                if (registration.installing) {
                    serviceWorker = registration.installing;
                } else if (registration.waiting) {
                    serviceWorker = registration.waiting;
                } else if (registration.active) {
                    serviceWorker = registration.active;
                }
                
            }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
```

**Also,in the Tutorial provided by google in** [Google official Doc](https://youtu.be/BsCBCudx58g) ,**Use Server Key instead of api key otherwise error will surely come.**

Comment: Now days mostly browsers support service worker but check first whether browser support service worker or not.